# mvc - url.action - second argument is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Strange problem with my code - please, look at it:

```
@Url.Action("IdeaVote","Ideas", new { IdeaID = "1", vote = "For" })
```

values in method (get from debugger):

> IdeaID=1, vote=null

And now some magic tips (reverse vote and IdeaID).

```
@Url.Action("IdeaVote","Ideas", new { vote = "For", IdeaID = "1" })
```

Again values in method (get from debugger):

> vote=for, IdeaID=null

Method IdeaVote (parameters)

```
    public int IdeaVote(string vote, string IdeaID)
```

My question is - Why second argument is always null? Why this situation happend?

Regards

EDIT:

My jQuery method with url.action

```
    $.get("@Url.Action("IdeaVote","Ideas", new { IdeaID = "1", vote = "For" })",function(data)
    {
        if (data == 1) {
            $("#imageVoteAgainst").css("border-width", 0);
            $("#imageVoteFor").css("border-width", 1);
        }

    });
```

Comment: How does your controller look like - I mean the parameters?

Comment: How are you using your Url.Action? Is this being used with to set the href of and anchor tag?

Comment: look at edit now. Regards

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You didn't post the URL generated by your code, but in generl `Url.Action` creates HTML-encoded links, so I think the problem in your case is that `&` sign is replaced with `&amp;`. Try using `Html.Raw` helper to decode this:

```
"@Html.Raw(Url.Action("IdeaVote","Ideas", new { IdeaID = "1", vote = "For" }))"
```